# Non Breaking space converted to a strange charcter (encoding);

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have imported some text from `ISO-8859-1` to a `UTF8` database 
after import i found that `&nbsp;` has become two weird characters `Â*`
when I checked this with phpmyadmin I found it looks like `Â` the Asterisk doesn't exist so I couldn't match it on a replace query , all what I want is to replace this character with a space via mysql query.
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some check , I could match the required character combination `Â+space` I could match the space with `alt+0160` not normal space

Answer (score 0):

Try using utf8_encode before inserting it into the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can UPDATE table fields with `REPLACE(text_string, from_string, to_string)` function.. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: I know how to replace , my problem is that I can't match this character

Comment: can you find it inside imported data with normal SELECT and reuse it?